# Visual Studio tooltips when hover over C# keywords

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Is there any tools from Microsoft or maybe 3rd party with tooltips when hoovering over C# keywords?

Maybe it is already in VS and it just need to be turned on?

Something like:

Hover over 'private' keyword will display tooltip with:

```
The private keyword is a member access modifier. 
Private members are accessible only within the body of the class
or the struct in which they are declared.
```

Something like that.

Comment: I don't think that there any such addon for VS. But you can try to search it on the [Market](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vs), and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) might help you. Unfortunately you request is to unusual and will looks to stainge for those who know c#.

Comment: No, there is no substitute for *learning the language*. There aren't that many keywords; just [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx).

Comment: @CodyGray : Your comment is not helpful at all. 
There are some keywords where I am not using at work at all. 
There are some keywords where I want to be sure that I am not misunderstood or forgot their meaning.
For example in my programs I am not using at all 'implicit', and very rarely yield or volatile. 
Of course, I will remember all definitions in the end, but when I just need take a quick look to be sure, it would be nice to take this quick look in VS.
Maybe even with some additional information. To not jumping with your focus to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any 3rd party tooltip extensions that I am aware of, however you could use **[Peek Help](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/12/27/view-help-with-in-same-code-window-peek-help-in-visual-studio-2013/)**. It isn't a tooltip, however it is a means to view the documentation.

In your example, right click on `private` and click on **Peek Help**. Alternatively you could use the keyboard shortcut `Alt+F1`.